# How to create Salesforce application that will send record to external web service when record created/changed

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, appexchange, connected-apps, app

I want to develop **Salesforce app** that will **send record** to **external web service** when new record created or record changed(Updated/deleted). And easily install on any user's Salesforce profile. Is this Possible?
Thanks.

Comment: It is definitely possible. But what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have created Apex Trigger on Object that will send record details to Apex class and Apex class will send details to external web service.
I want make this process in One step using sales force Application.

Comment: I did it before but I am not sure how yours look like.Mine one is a scheduled class that run batch job daily then  create/update data in the external app using HttpCall out.One of the key is, you need to setup authentication from the external webservice.

Comment: Fenil, if you've done all you've said can you explain exactly where you're stuck?

Comment: LaceySnr, What i have done will working fine but only in a profile/account.
I have to create this process in multiple account. For that, i have to create classes and trigger in all user's account and that's not reliable.  I want to make a bundle/App that will easily install in user's account in a click and all function will merge in one app And that entire process will work for the any user after App installation. Got it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried outbound messaging feature in salesforce?

all you need is to create a workflow rule, add "Outbound Message", then select field to send along with the desired endpoint URL.

Pretty easy and can be setup to send data to endpoint on update/create, and runs as system so no sharing is enforced (can apply to all profiles).

https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_setting_up.htm